# Eliminar duplicado obteniendo maximo valor de un registro

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Tengo una tabla en una bbdd de mariaDB con la siguiente información, este solo es un registro.
Estoy intentando eliminar el registro duplicado por Id Petición que tiene Fecha Fin Vacia (es decir,   duplicado de ORDEN 6 que tiene fecha vacia). Pero no se como obtener el máximo de las INC y eliminarlo.

| Id Petición | Orden | ULTIMO | Fecha Inicio | Fecha Fin |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| INC0000062102 | 2 |  | 2021-02-24 10:34:43 | 2021-02-24 17:44:09 |
| INC0000062102 | 3 |  | 2021-02-24 17:44:09 | 2021-02-24 18:49:09 |
| INC0000062102 | 4 |  | 2021-02-24 18:49:09 | 2021-02-24 18:57:37 |
| INC0000062102 | 5 |  | 2021-02-24 18:57:37 | 2021-02-24 19:13:21 |
| INC0000062102 | **6** | ULTIMO | 2021-02-24 19:13:21 | **0000-00-00 00:00:00** |
| INC0000062102 | 6 |  | 2021-02-24 19:13:21 | 2021-03-01 21:28:52 |
| INC0000062102 | 7 |  | 2021-03-01 21:28:52 | 2021-03-22 14:25:14 |
| INC0000062102 | 8 |  | 2021-03-22 14:25:14 | 2021-03-22 15:20:02 |
| INC0000062102 | 9 |  | 2021-03-22 15:20:02 | 2021-03-23 09:01:25 |
| INC0000062102 | 10 |  | 2021-03-23 09:01:25 | 2021-03-23 09:13:54 |
| INC0000062102 | 11 |  | 2021-03-23 09:13:54 | 2021-03-31 08:17:47 |
| INC0000062102 | 12 |  | 2021-03-31 08:17:47 | 2021-03-31 15:13:41 |
| INC0000062102 | 13 | ULTIMO | 2021-03-31 15:13:41 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |

Es decir, partiendo de lo anterior, necesito obtener la siguiente tabla:

| Id Petición | Orden | ULTIMO | Fecha Inicio | Fecha Fin |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| INC0000062102 | 2 |  | 2021-02-24 10:34:43 | 2021-02-24 17:44:09 |
| INC0000062102 | 3 |  | 2021-02-24 17:44:09 | 2021-02-24 18:49:09 |
| INC0000062102 | 4 |  | 2021-02-24 18:49:09 | 2021-02-24 18:57:37 |
| INC0000062102 | 5 |  | 2021-02-24 18:57:37 | 2021-02-24 19:13:21 |
| INC0000062102 | 6 |  | 2021-02-24 19:13:21 | 2021-03-01 21:28:52 |
| INC0000062102 | 7 |  | 2021-03-01 21:28:52 | 2021-03-22 14:25:14 |
| INC0000062102 | 8 |  | 2021-03-22 14:25:14 | 2021-03-22 15:20:02 |
| INC0000062102 | 9 |  | 2021-03-22 15:20:02 | 2021-03-23 09:01:25 |
| INC0000062102 | 10 |  | 2021-03-23 09:01:25 | 2021-03-23 09:13:54 |
| INC0000062102 | 11 |  | 2021-03-23 09:13:54 | 2021-03-31 08:17:47 |
| INC0000062102 | 12 |  | 2021-03-31 08:17:47 | 2021-03-31 15:13:41 |
| INC0000062102 | 13 | ULTIMO | 2021-03-31 15:13:41 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |

eliminando o no mostrando el siguiente registro

| Id Petición | Orden | ULTIMO | Fecha Inicio | Fecha Fin |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| INC0000062102 | **6** | ULTIMO | 2021-02-24 19:13:21 | **0000-00-00 00:00:00** |

he probado muchas formas pero no lo he conseguido, la query con la que obtengo los duplicados es la siguiente:

```
``SELECT `Id Petición`, Orden, Count(Orden) AS CuentaDeOrden,
`Fecha Inicio`,`Fecha Fin`, ULTIMO 
FROM incidencias_exportar
GROUP BY `Id Petición`, Orden
HAVING (((Count(Orden))>1));
```

¿alguna idea?
muchas gracias

Comment: Como esta planteada la tabla??. Por lo que se ve, tu PK abarca IdPeticion, Orden, Ultimo y posiblemente fecha Inicio??. Pone la consulta que estas intentando hacer. Así a simple vista primero tendrías que identificar los registros duplicados y luego, a esos duplicados, pregunta cuales tienen la fecha fin menor a la fecha inicio. Esto se va a dar solamente en los casos en que la fecha sea 0.

Comment: hola, le he dado muchas vueltas, pero a la hora de responder tus preguntas y ejecutando lo siguiente: 

SELECT `Id Petición`, Orden, Count(Orden) AS CuentaDeOrden, `Fecha Inicio`,`Fecha Fin`, ULTIMO 
FROM incidencias_exportar
GROUP BY `Id Petición`, Orden
HAVING (((Count(Orden))>1));

obtengo el registro duplicado a eliminar de la tabla principal.

INC0000062102 6 2 24/02/2021 19:13 0000-00-00 00:00:00 ULTIMO

pero no se como eliminarlo de la tabla principal.

Comment: como he visto que la respuesta no permite formato, he editado el texto y lo he puesto mas claro todo.

Comment: Pides varias cosas diferentes: fechas vacías, máximos de INCxxx, ¿podrías poner ejemplos ejemplos más cortos y concretos? Por ejemplo, ¿por qué el 13 aparece en el resultado que esperas si su fecha está vacía?

Comment: Hola, realmente lo que necesito quitar o filtrar es el registro duplicado que tiene fecha fin vacía. La 13 no está duplicado. 
Había puesto la fecha maxima porque quizás podría calcularlo obteniendo el valor duplicado y con fecha fin mayor en la propia consulta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Borra haciendo `JOIN` con los duplicados:

```
DELETE i
  FROM incidencias_exportar i
    INNER JOIN ( SELECT `Id Petición`, Orden
                   FROM incidencias_exportar
                   GROUP BY `Id Petición`, Orden
                   HAVING count(1) > 1
               ) duplicados
      USING (`Id Petición`, Orden)
  WHERE `Fecha Fin` is null
```

Comment: mil gracias!!! he cambiado el is null por = "0000-00-00 00:00:00" y ha funcionado al a perfección.

Answer (score 0):

Si agrupas, deberías utilizar una función de totales para aquellos campos por los que no agrupes. Prueba así:

```
SELECT `Id Petición`, Orden, 
    MAX(`Fecha Inicio`),MAX(`Fecha Fin`),MAX(ULTIMO)
    FROM incidencias_exportar
    GROUP BY 1,2;
```

Para eliminar el máximo INC de tus listados, puedes hacer algo así:

```
SELECT `Id Petición`, Orden, 
    MAX(`Fecha Inicio`),MAX(`Fecha Fin`),MAX(ULTIMO)
    FROM incidencias_exportar
    WHERE `Id Petición` NOT IN (
        SELECT MAX(`Id Petición`)
            FROM incidencias_exportar   
    )
    GROUP BY 1,2;
```

Comment: hola, la verdad es que esta muy bien y mas sencilla de lo que pensaba, pero al realizarlo asi, en la linea 6 me trae tambien el ULTIMO que no deberia de mostrarmelo, pero creando una tabla auxiliar y ordenado Id peticion por fecha maxima puedo obtener el ULTIMO real. muchas gracias por la ayuda!!